# AssociationMap to query Dataset across levels?

Tags: functional-style, dataset, associations

Is there a way to operate on Dataset across levels to apply a function `f` to a `key -> value` pair in an Association as follows:

```
pivotApply[f_, key_ -> value_] :=  key -> f[key, value]
```

For example, take the Titanic dataset and pivot up "class":

```
titanicClass = titanic[GroupBy[Key@"class"], KeyDrop[Key@"class"]];
```

For this problem, assume only titanicClass. `"class"` key has been deleted and so can't referenced. The motivation is tree-structured data where it would be inefficient to insert the keys `{"1st"...}` at the deeper level.

Here `foo` represents a "client" function to be applied to deeper level data but depenent on class values.

**EDIT // #age >= 18 &**

```
foo["1st", data_] := Dataset[data][All, #age >= 18 &];
foo["2nd", data_] := Dataset[data][All, "sex"];
foo["3rd", data_] := Dataset[data][All, "survived"];
```

Is there a way to avoid inefficient downcasting to Normal and back to Dataset to use AssociationMap? Also note there are Datasets nested in a larger one, which should also be cast to Lists (since there is an outer Dataset).

```
AssociationMap[pivotApply[foo, #] &, titanicClass // Normal] // Dataset
```

[image]

Is there a way to query Datasets across levels like this? This seems extremely roundabout, but haven't figured an implementation using, say Keys and Values and related Dataset operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: the question has evolved, as has my understanding of it.  My response has been changed completely, although I have kept my earlier responses below.*

If we can drop the requirement to use `AssociationMap`, `pivotApply` and `foo`, then we can generate the desired output directly using subqueries:

```
titanicClass @
  { "1st" -> Query[All, #age > 18&]
  , "2nd" -> Query[All, "sex"]
  , "3rd" -> Query[All, "survived"]
  }
```

[image: dataset query screenshot]

As requested, the inner lists are not wrapped in `Dataset`.

---

**Original Responses**

If we are willing to dispense with the requirement to use `AssociationMap`, here are a couple of options to "query across levels" in the described manner.

If we introduce `bar` as a slightly rewritten form of the function `foo` from the question...

```
bar[a_] := bar[a, a@"class"]
bar[a_, "1st"] := a@"age"
bar[a_, "2nd"] := a@"sex"
bar[a_, "3rd"] := a@"survived"
```

... then the function can be called directly within the dataset query after grouping:

```
titanic[GroupBy @ Key @ "class", All, bar]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Alternatively, we could dispense with the function altogether and extract the various components with an inline `Switch` statement.

```
titanic[
  GroupBy @ Key @ "class"
, All
, Switch[#class, "1st", #age, "2nd", #sex, "3rd", #survived]&
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

---

**Edit: Starting From `titanicClass`**

My original response mistakenly assumed that `titanic` was the input data.  The question has been revised to emphasize that `titanicClass` is actually the input data.  Under that assumption, we can generate the described output as follows...

First, we supplement the definition of `pivotApply` to include a one-argument "lifting" form of the operator:

```
pivotApply[f_] := pivotApply[f, #]&
```

Next, we create the function `baz` which is yet another variation upon `foo`:

```
baz["1st", a_] := a[[All, "age"]]
baz["2nd", a_] := a[[All, "sex"]]
baz["3rd", a_] := a[[All, "survived"]]
```

Now, we can generate the required output using `AssociationMap`:

```
titanicClass[AssociationMap @ pivotApply @ baz]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Once again, we can dispense with the function `baz` and express the query inline if desired:

```
titanicClass @ AssociationMap @ pivotApply[
  #2[[All, # /. {"1st" -> "age", "2nd" -> "sex", "3rd" -> "survived"}]]&
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I would accept an approach that avoids AssociationMap, however, I reworded question to highlight that "class" is not an available key. (Assume a tree structure where it's not available to begin with and it's too inefficient to insert it into large HRS data at the deeper level.

Comment: Please see the new section in my response, "starting from titanicClass".

Comment: Your solution (with 'baz') references the data via Part, eg `a[[All,"age"]]` but it doesn't leverage Dataset's named slot semantics. How to pass a function eg: #age >= 18 &? (This would be a variation on `foo`). Also, can this be done with your inline version?

Comment: Okay, I think I finally see what you are after -- fingers crossed :).  Please see my all-new response.

Comment: This is a great solution WReach, thanks. I will accept if you factor it through something like pivotApply b/c in general the top-level keys `{"1st"...}` are not know a priori, and so the `Query`'s should be threaded programmatically.

Comment: I accepted anyway, b/c it's easy enough to parametrize the query by simplifying `foo` as `foo["1st"] := Query[All, #age >= 18 &]` ... and then using: `AssociationMap[foo, titanicClass // Keys // Normal] // Normal`

Answer (score 4):

Using this helper function

```
ClearAll[keyStrip]
keyStrip[Key[k_]|{Key[k_]}] := k;
keyStrip[expr_] := expr;
```

you can achieve what you asked for as

```
titanicClass[MapIndexed[foo[keyStrip[First@#2], #1] &]]
```

The general issue about being able to reference some elements of the parent structures inside child structures during the traversal (in the queries) is more complicated. As of now, `Dataset` query language does not, as far as I know, easily allow this, but such capabilities may be added in the future.

**EDIT**

Here is a version which does not use the `foo` function, but uses `Lookup` and specifies the lookup explicitly via an association:

```
titanicClass[
  MapIndexed[
    Lookup[
      #1, 
      <|"1st" -> "age", "2nd" -> "sex", "3rd" -> "survived"|>[keyStrip[#2]]
    ] &
  ]
]
```

Comment: This works but was hoping to avoid wrapping "data" in Dataset for each call. Is there a way to make this approach work inline?

Comment: @alancalvitti I was using your own function `foo`. Now you say you don't want to use it. Your question, precisely, was *"Is there a way to avoid inefficient downcasting to Normal and back to Dataset to use AssociationMap?"*, asked about your last line of code,  - and this was precisely what I was answering. I will revisit this later if I have the time. Try to formulate your questions better, at least if you care about me answering them - this is not the first time I found your formulations vague, while I usually do not mis-interpret questions, and certainly have other things to do as well.

Comment: I always appreciate your insight. I slightly reworded my Q. The function `foo` stands for a "client" function to be applied to the data, so it must be used in the answer. The question is how to apply it, while retaining Dataset named slot semantics, but as operators without having to create Dataset and subsequently Normal'izing. Let me know if this clears it up.

Comment: @alancalvitti See if my edit works for you.

Comment: As per my comment to WReach, `foo` is using named slot semantics - that's the reason for casting to Dataset. What if `foo["1st", data_] := Dataset[data][All, {"age" -> (# >= 18 &)}]` ?

Comment: My fault, above: Dataset[data][All, #age >= 18 &]

Comment: @alancalvitti I think, at some point, when you make your queries more and more general,  you have two choices: either use internal `Dataset` wrappers, as you do, or write your own custom transformation, using only raw lists and associations, and not using the `Dataset` syntax. In any case, for your last comment, the recommendations of WReach may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
titanic[GroupBy[Key@"class" -> (Switch[#class,
    "1st", #age,
    "2nd", #sex,
    "3rd", #survived] &)
]] // Normal // Dataset
```

[image]